# Will transfering my domain affect my emails in Office365?

Tags: office365

A customer of mine has a domain name registered at Wix.com, and some email adresses at Office365 with that domain. I will soon have that domain name transfered to One.com.

Will the email addresses and inboxes be affected by this? If yes, what do I need to do?

I am afraid of loosing all the sent and received emails in the inboxes. Can that happen? Or what is worst case scenario, just that I will not be able to receive new emails?

**Clarification**:
Will my email addresses and inboxes continue to work just fine in Office365 after transfering my domain name from Wix.com to One.com? Or will I need to change for example some configuration for them to work? And, is there a risk for all the emails to dissappear from Office365 after transfering my domain name?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Ramhound Sure, I have added some clarification.